# Phrase choice for "one of x preferred colours" when two colour choices are equivalent

Tags: phrases, numbers, expression-choice

Let us say that Eve has 3 preferred colours:

1. Red
2. Green
3. Blue

Of those 3 colours, Eve prefers red the most, but her preference for green and blue are identical.

In English, would it be preferred for one to say/write ***green is one of her two most preferred colours*** or ***green is one of her three most preferred colours***?

Obviously, the latter statement is true regardless of whether or not the former is true (it is a superset), but I prefer to use whichever phrase is more specific, clear, and accurate.

Comment: Green is one of her three _favourite_ colours, but she prefers red.

Comment: @KateBunting In addition to Peter's helpful answer, if you would like to add your comment as an answer, I will be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

The strongest statement you can make in this situation is that green is one of her three most preferred colours, as saying that it is one of her two most preferred colours implies that there are two colours preferred to all others.

Answer (score 1):

We usually speak of a person's *favourite* colour or colours. *Prefer* implies a choice between two things (or a small number).

> Green is one of her three favourite colours, but she prefers red.

Comment: Thanks Kate.  Upvoted. :)